# Why aren't copulas a central topic in texts on probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory

It seems to me that graduate level texts on probability theory hardly ever mention copula functions, let alone do a comprehensive review on the topic. Can anyone enlighten me why this is?

Answer (score 4):

Because copulas are used for applied generation of empirical data, and the theory of joint pdfs(cdf) is not covered in applied methods.  Another explanation regarding course instruction is that there is a general lack of instruction on simulation in graduate-level statistics courses.  Specifically, pdfs and cdfs of joint distributions are mostly covered in *theoretical* statistics courses, where simulation is not a main topic because it involves *applied* (empirical) data generation.  Empirical data issues surrounding **creation of data** are not discussed in statistical theory courses.

You commonly need to take a graduate-level statistics course on computer programming which covers Bayesian simulation, MCMC, etc., and "hope" that copulas are covered -- but they won't be.   There simply isn't enough time to cover Copulas in statistical theory courses.

Overall, copulas combine joint pdf(cdf) theory and applied simulation methods, which is quite unique in terms of application.

Comment: Also, it is rather new. It would more probably be covered in applied courses when it is needed for the application.